# Google chrome extension error when debugger open only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a ajax request to a server inside a google chrome extension. I am using angular with it too and the code is inside the controller. The request works fine generally, but when I have the the DevTools open it throws an error. This is the relevant part of the code:

```
    $scope.sendLink = function (){
        chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
            var url = tabs[0].url;
            var date = new Date();
            var xPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xPost.open("POST", **URL HERE*",true);
            xPost.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xPost.send(JSON.stringify({"name":$scope.name,"url":url,"date":date}));
        });

    }
```

When I hit inspect element on the extension, and then do the request, the tabs array come back as empty. It works fine if the devTools window is closed. I can't figure out why that is the case. Any explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: http://imgur.com/Ax9OKrf - This contains a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You could have changed the javascript engine behavior via chrome-dev-tools. This would get activated only when the dev-tools are open.

For instance, once I found that a mate of mine had turned-off javascript using the chrome-dev-tools. His app wasn't executing when the chrome-dev-tools were open...